# Film about a man playing a virtual reality game who finds a woman that he falls in love with

Tags: story-identification, movie, virtual-worlds

The film is about a man that lives in an apartment, he is constantly playing a virtual reality game. The majority of the film is him in the game. He finds a woman in the game that he falls in love with. He’s looking for her in the club and they finally meet she has friends in the game who laugh at him. In the end it shows the location where the apartment is and it looks like a terrible place to live.

I can only recall a very small detail of this film. It was a sad film, the main character (man)was living in a Bad condition (not much food, dirty and messy place). His apartment was a sky scraper type but also seemed to be deserted in the middle of nowhere. It seems his only happiness was playing on the computer. He’s playing a game where it’s like an MMO, lots of people around him in the game but it only focuses on a woman character, and through the film he is chasing her, she’s walking away from him so he can find her. It’s a realistic film but when the game is on the film becomes a fantasy. The MMO was mainly in dark sceneries and impersonating realistic life events such as being with friends and partying but it didn't have a purpose. the characters and scenery didn’t look very detailed either almost like a 480p resolution first person.

I watched this film about 4-5 years ago (2015-2016).

Comment: Welcome to the site! This seems very generic - is there any more detail you can add e.g. from our [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) [on](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) asking good story-ID questions? Also, is there anything sci-fi or fantasy about this film: e.g. does the game come to life, or is it just a realistic film about a man dwelling in his own fantasies?

Comment: What exactly makes it science-fiction or fantasy? Nowadays virtual reality MMOs are a thing, and people in love with virtual characters or avatars have been around for some time as well; unless you say it's from, like, the 80's, or has more definite science-fiction elements (do people from the game cross over to real life maybe?) I don't think it's on-topic for this site.

Comment: Is this just [Ready Player One?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready_Player_One_(film))

Comment: I watched this film about 4-5 years ago so it definitely not past 2016. I apologise if this is not the right topic for the page I assumed it was a movie finder.

Comment: @Alonso24: We do identify science fiction and fantasy movies. :) But we do ask that they be science fiction or fantasy. Can you point at some more fantastic events? Like, is the MMO absurdly realistic maybe?

Comment: The MMO was mainly in dark sceneries and impersonating realistic life events such as being with friends and partying but it didn't have a purpose. the characters and scenery didn’t look very detailed either almost like a  480p resolution first person.

Comment: Ah, that is an important detail you may want to add to your question. As it is, with you describing the game as "fantasy" that they were playing elves, or something like that. So this is a bit more like Second Life? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Life

Comment: The movie is called Her. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Her_%28film%29 . The movie is from 2013. He constantly plays video games. The question is not offtopic, because there is AI in the movie in the form of virtual assistant called Samantha. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7__q1xUCaM

Comment: *Her* does not fit the description the OP gives.

Comment: Was this a Live-Action Film?  Animated? (And, if so, what style: CGI, drawn, cell-shaded, etc) Both? (i.e. different styles for the "Real Life" and "In-Game" portions)  Can you remember any character descriptions/appearances?  What language did you watch it in?

Comment: I watched it on youtube